# Array count is 0 & UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I am trying to add an object to my **mutable array** but when when I do it crashes. I am sure that my array has been **alloc** and **init**.

Here is my code:
[image: code]

I have tried to figure out what is wrong, it seems my code works perfectly fine if I out comment the line [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths...]
The only problem is that my tableView is not updating then :'( (if I out comment the line).

Here is  my error msg:
[image: Here is my error msg]

And here is my consol when I have out commented inserRowsAtIndexPaths... line:
[image]

As you can see everything seems to work fine.

Extra info:
[image: UITableViewDataSource]

I don't know if you need it but here is my UITableViewDataSource :)

Thank you
Anders

Comment: Why are you using images to show us text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you never alloc-init'd your array. If that's the case, you're trying to stuff items into something that just isn't there. You say you're sure that it has been already, but I would do some debugging to make double sure. That was what caused me to get this same error message; I had accidentally deleted my init method earlier.

Comment: If that were the case, wouldn't the numberOfRowsInSection method simply return 0, leading to cellForRowAtIndexPath to not be called at all? In any case, I think it's a good idea to inspect the array.

Comment: @fiorgodx Okay I figured it out. The problem was my array. But I don't get why my numberOfRowsInSection was increasing when I was adding items to the array.

Answer (score 0):

When I take look at your logs, I can see this '*Indexpath = 0*' which means that you have nothing in your Array (*self.budgets.items*), try to debug your dataSource array(Actual data you want to display on tableView) first.